# Get return of the method from Action.Invoke

Tags: c#

I am trying to implement small console-like commands to ASP .Net Core App. I have a class which stores names and method that should be run:

```
public class ActionCenter
{
    public string ActionName { get; set; }
    public Action ActionStart { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a list `List<ActionCenter> Actions` where I store all the commands and methods associated with them. To run method I can do `Actions[0].ActionStart.Invoke`, but I do not have return of the method. I tried `Task<object>` but cannot convert `System.Action` to `System.Func<object>`. Is there a way to have return from methods designed this way if not what is the right way?

Comment: `Action` type does not return a value. It is a delegate for `void` methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is stated at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action(v=vs.110).aspx) an `Action`:

> Encapsulates a method that has no parameters and **does not return a**
>   **value**.

```
public delegate void Action()
```

That being said you cannot achieve that you want with an action. On the other hand, a `Func<TResult>`:

> Encapsulates a method that has no parameters and returns a value of
>   the type specified by the TResult parameter.

So in your case you need a `Func` rather than an `Action`. If we say that you expect your method to return always an `int`, you should have a `Func<int>` etc. Furthremore, Funcs as Actions can get a list of parameters, if your method is going to have any. So for instance, if your have a method that takes two parameters of type int and returns another int, the signarture of your Func, it would be `Func<int,int,int>`.